# Is there a way to automate saving a PDF version of an HTML formatted report whenever it is viewed in the browser?

Tags: html, pdf

I  am working with SQL Server and C# to create individual employee reports. I am using HTML and CSS to format the reports and display in a browser. The customer also wants a printout of every report. I would like to have a formatted PDF version of the report automatically saved to a folder on the server whenever a report is viewed in the browser. I could create a process to print all of the PDF pages at one time.

Comment: You can convert the html to pdf like explained [here](https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e). Then, send it in the server on page load.

Comment: Yes you can, research mPDF for server PHP  side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the generation of the PDF, as it happens I had to do something similar a couple of years ago.

I was generating HTML reports from C# that I needed to convert to PDF.

There is a nuget package named [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf) that uses [wkhtmlopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert HTML to PDF.

At the time I also wrote a bit of blurb on this [subject on my blog here!](http://oceanairdrop.blogspot.com/2018/09/outputting-html-content-to-pdf-in-c.html)

For your scenario, when the customer requests a report, on the server side you could generate the html as you are now.  Then you could use OpenHtmlToPdf to additionally generate a PDF version on the server at the same time.

All you would then need to work out is how to get the PDF link address to the user (email, web link, etc)